# Spring Boot @Insert an Entity Which Attributes are Custom Objects

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ibatis, mapper

I have a mapper that looks like this:

```
@Insert ("INSERT INTO `Order`(.....) VALUES(.....) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...")
@Options(flushCache=FlushCachePolicy.DEFAULT)
Integer upsertAccount(Account account);
```

Everything works fine until I have an entity which attribute is a custom object like this:

```
public class Order{
    .....
    .....
    .....
    private Address address;
    .....
    .....
}
```

I got the following error:

```
2021-Aug-06 11:59:02.917 ERROR [main] o.m.s.m.MapperFactoryBean - Error while adding the mapper 'interface com.myproject.xxx.mapper.CommonMapper' to configuration.
org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Could not find value method on SQL annotation.  Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Type handler was null on parameter mapping for property 'address'. It was either not specified and/or could not be found for the javaType (com.myproject.xxx.model.Address) : jdbcType (null) combination.
```

What should I do to make it work? Thank you

Comment: what is address? A foreign key value or a whole object to be stored as jsonb?

Comment: @devReddit Order is a JSON which has an attribute address (which is of course a JSON object too). The legacy code uses this ```T instance = gson.fromJson(j.getJSONObject(i).toString(), entity);``` which, of course, causes error since address was a ```String```. So, I had to replace it with new custom object, however, another error occured (the one posted on the question). Should I make the Address entity on my DB?

Comment: If address is not reusable and defined, it's better to consider that Address as jsonb instead of entity.